# I update anaconda in EC2, then I can't open Jupyter notebook in terminal, what should I do?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I just followed [this](https://sites.google.com/site/kittipat/programming-with-python/updateanacondaanditspackagesonubuntu) command line to update anaconda, then when I type `jupyter notebook`, I got this error:

```
udacity@ip-172-31-25-67:~$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/carnd/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, in <module>
    import notebook.notebookapp
  File "/home/carnd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .services.contents.filemanager import FileContentsManager
  File "/home/carnd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .filecheckpoints import FileCheckpoints
  File "/home/carnd/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filecheckpoints.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import tz
ImportError: cannot import name 'tz'
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda upgrade jupyter notebook
```

You can find more information in the [conda documentation](https://conda.io/docs/commands.html).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by removing my conda environment then `conda clean --all`. In my case I think it was to do with a corrupt local cache of the `notebook` library